# How to display input button from two different form in single line

Tags: html, css

I have to display both these buttons in single line. 
I tried adding **style="{display:block-inline;}">** in form element as suggested somewhere but that too didn't help me. Any idea how to do it ?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form >
              <input  type="submit" value="Button1" />
            </form>
            <form >
              <input  type="submit" value="Button2" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both forms in their own div and use float in your css.
See fiddle example:

```
<body>
<div>
    <div id=form1>
        <form >
            <input  type="submit" value="Button1" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <divid=form2>
    <form >
        <input  type="submit" value="Button2" />
    </form>
        </div>
</div>
</body>


#form1{
float:left;

}
#form2{
 float:left;   
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5mcffrv9/

Answer (score 1):

Inline-block works perfect. Take a look here. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/xh89n3vv/)

HTML

```
<form >
  <input type="submit" value="Button1" />
</form>
<form >
  <input type="submit" value="Button2" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
form { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

Add

```
<div class="name">

</div>
```

to your forms each one.

Then in css add

```
.name{
float: left;
}
```

or

```
.name{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kb86veLk/1/

Displaying with inline block
like so
https://jsfiddle.net/kb86veLk/2/

is probably the best way though.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this:

**CSS**

```
form{display:inline;}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6h2v8khr/)